# How to enable break point in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api

I am trying to put break point to web api service which is written in visual studio 2017.
However, I am unable to see the option to put break point.

I have used F9 and Alt+F9 to put breakpoint to my code.

Still its not working.

Kindly let me know how to enable break point in visual studio 2017

Comment: just click on the grey bar to the left of  the line of code you want to break on.

Comment: Go to Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run, check if 'On Run, when build or deployment errors occur' is set to 'Do not launch'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to talk your cursor to the extreme end of the code editor, very close to that place that as the line number. Then click it, you should see a red circle there. That is your breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

click on the left side of the line number. A red dot should appear

Answer (score 0):

You can create breakpoints in Visual Studio in several ways. One way is to have your cursor on the line you want to have a breakpoint, and then press <kbd>F9</kbd>. You will see a red circle on the left indicating a breakpoint.

However, you can also click to the left of the line number you want to add a breakpoint on, and that will also create a breakpoint.

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/media/dbg-tour-set-a-breakpoint.gif?view=vs-2019

Also, see this for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019